rn-fetch-blob is giving incorrect result for RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
I am using RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs to know the location of Downloads folder so that I can download my file there. But even on a rela device it is giving me the location in which a folder named "emulated" is there and an error is thrown that cannot find this location. Below is code. Thanks in advance.
const response = await fetch(url, {
          method,
          headers,
          body
        });
    
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Failed to fetch file');
        }
    
        // Get the file as a blob
        const blob = await response.blob();
    
        // Define the path where you want to save the file3
        console.log("path",RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs)
        const filePath = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir}/${fileName}`; // Change the filename and extension as needed
        RNFetchBlob.config({
          fileCache: true,
          addAndroidDownloads: {
            useDownloadManager: true,
            notification: true,
            path: filePath, // The path where the file will be saved
            description: 'Downloading the file',
          },
        });
        
        // Save the file using RNFetchBlob
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = () => {
          const base64data = fileReader.result;
          console.log({filePath})
          RNFetchBlob.fs
            .writeFile(filePath, base64data.split(',')[1], 'base64')
            .then(() => {
              console.log('File saved successfully:', filePath);
              // You can now notify the user or open the file
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error('Error saving file:', error);
            });
        };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);


i prefer react-native-fs which is better and can same methods can be accessed,
for RNfetchBlob
try
const fileName = 'document.pdf';  const destPath = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir + '/' + fileName;
and console the destpath
